# Google Distance Matrix API call not working in particular Server

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I have been struggling a lot to fix an issue related with Google distance matrix API call. Please the below code which I use to calculated distance between two calls. It work perfectly fine in localhost and one website hosted in Hostgator.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```html
$details = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=95864&destinations=91367&key=<API_KEY>' ; 
 
$json = file_get_contents($details);
  $details = json_decode($json, TRUE); 

  $distanceinmiles  =  ( $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'] * 0.000621371);  

  if($distanceinmiles > 0)
  echo "Distance: " . $distanceinmiles  ;
else
 echo "Bad request";
```

is to be replaced with original API key.

The same code works in http://egressacademy.in/distance.php and shows the distance properly.

However, when the code is checked from another website from Enom hosting provider it failed.

I have also added Key restriction in Google API console for both server IP addresses.

Can anyone please advise how to fix this issues?

Comment: Have you listed your domain in your Google account? Requests from the domains which you had registered with API key are only considered as valid

Comment: Hi. Yes, I have listed server IP addresses. Both servers IP addresses for the two website. The one hosted in enom is not working while the other hosted in hostgator works fine.

Comment: Not the IP address but I am asking about the domain?

Comment: There are also API keys which are specific to domain. Share some knowledge about your API key as well

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I have setup the distance calculator form here at http://egressacademy.in/distance-calculator.php. It work perfectly fine. But when I use this code in another different domain by Enom, it failed.

Comment: Do add your domain to your google account for it to make it work. Or you can generate an API key for that domain as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its problem with you php apache server. You have to enable

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

enable it then it will work again.